# How does nginx behave when fail_timeout and proxy_connect_timeout are inconsistent?

Tags: nginx

This question is about [`proxy_connect_timeout`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_connect_timeout) and [`fail_timeout`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#fail_timeout) and how nginx determines failed upstream servers.

Nginx documentation states that `fail_timeout`:

> sets the time during which the specified number of unsuccessful attempts to communicate with the server should happen to consider the server unavailable

The documentation states the following about `proxy_connect_timeout`:

> Defines a timeout for establishing a connection with a proxied server. It should be noted that this timeout cannot usually exceed 75 seconds.

The documentation also states that the default values of `fail_timeout` and `proxy_connect_timeout` are 10 and 60 seconds, respectively.

How does nginx deal with inconsistencies between these two configuration parameters? Does one take precedence over the other? Does it take the shorter period of the two?